# Extracting info from webpage via python

Tags: python

I'd like to ask somebody with experience with headless browsers and python if it's possible to extract box info with distance from closest strike on webpage below. Till now I was using python bs4 but since everything is driven by jQuery here simple download of webpage doesn't work. I found PhantomJS but I wasn't able extract it too so I am not sure if it's possible. Thanks for hints.

https://lxapp.weatherbug.net/v2/lxapp_impl.html?lat=49.13688&lon=16.56522&v=1.2.0

Comment: Yes, it's possible: render the page in a headless browser, use the remote control function to extract the text from the `closest-strike-distance-container` element. Alternatively, figure out how the API is used, possibly get permission to use the API, and get the information directly from the server.

Comment: Have you looked in to the API used to see if you can obtain the raw data directly, the same way that web page does? At a glance, it looks like you should be able to, and not need a headless browser at all, just (wget or curl) to query the API and return the result.

Comment: thanks for hint regarding remote control function, I will try it. I was checking API but wasn´t able to figure it out how is hash calculated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Linux question, it's a StackOverflow question, so I won't go into too much detail.

The thing you want to do can be easily done with Selenium. Selenium has both a headless mode, and a heady mode (where you can watch it open your browser and click on things). The DOM query API is a bit less extensive than bs4, but it does have nice visual query (location on screen) functions. So you would write a Python script that initializes Selenium, goes to your website and interacts with it. You may need to do some image recognition on screenshots at some point. It may be as simple as finding for a certain query image on the screen, or something much more complicated.

You'd have to go through the Selenium tutorials first to see how it works, which would take you 1-2 days. Then figure out what Selenium stuff you can use to do what you want, that depends on luck and whether what you want happens to be easy or hard for that particular website.

Instead of using Selenium, though, I recommend trying to reverse engineer the API. For example, the page you linked to hits `https://cmn-lx.pulse.weatherbug.net/data/lightning/v1/spark` with parameters like:

```
_
callback
isGpsLocation
location
locationtype
safetyMessage
shortMessage
units
verbose
authid
timestamp
hash
```

You can figure out by trial and error which ones you need and what to put in them. You can capture requests from your browser and then read them yourself. Then construct appropriate requests from a Python program and hit their API. It would save you from having to deal with a Web UI designed for humans.

Comment: You are right, I reached to this step but wasn´t able to figure it out how to bypass hash.